# User Name not listed on Log in Screen in Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: login, username

I have a desktop running Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
When I start Up I get a Grub screen to choose between Ubuntu and Windows. When I select Ubuntu I get a screen that shows a Person Icon and my User Name in an Orange box and underneath 'Not listed?' I have tried a number of things and can get into Ubuntu via the following.
I click on the Orange box and it changes to a black box and underneath it is the word Password and below a box to enter the password.This is followed on the next line with a Cancel box  a cog and a sign in box.
I click on the cog and a list appears 'Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Wayland and Unity.
I click on Unity, enter my password and click sign in. I get into Ubuntu. There is a window saying Ubuntu has had an error I click send and from then on everything works correctly.
I have tried selecting 'Ubuntu' and 'Ubuntu on Wayland' and both come up with a message 'Sorry, there is a problem. Please try again'

Comment: Was Ubuntu ever working properly before and this just happened, or is this a new installation or newly upgraded Ubuntu setup?

Comment: This problem suddenly happened  on Ubuntu 17.10 and I could not identify any reason. Ubuntu 18.04 was released so I upgraded hoping this may clear the problem or I could ask for help as 18.04 is supported by Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you check if you are using lightdm or gdm3? Do a "ps -ef | grep dm" to see which one is running.

Comment: Using gdm3     roger     1883  1874  0 17:55 tty2     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script /usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session unity-session.target
roger     1885  1883  0 17:55 tty2     00:01:54 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
roger    11085 11070  0 23:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dm

Comment: That's how the gdm3 greeter works, it presented you with a list of users to select for login. Some user are unlisted, so if you click that you can enter user name. After you selected the login user, you are given the option to pick various intefaces via the cog view selection. Some setup doesn't support wayland, and hence the error you see. If you don't like to use gdm3, do a 'dpkg-reconfigure lightdm' to switch back to the old greeter. You could also tweak how the gdm3 greeter work by editing '/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults'

Comment: #Bernard Wei. Thanks for your explanation.  I have tried to switch back but I get  'must run as root'.  I have also tried to switch and get message 'Permission denied'. What do I have to do?

Comment: when you get complains about must run as root, just prefix the commands with sudo, e.g., "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm"

Comment: #Bernard Wei. Thanks I have switched  back to lightdm.